# Toshiba Equium A110-252 laptop won't boot Windows

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, boot

I have a Toshiba Equium A110-252 laptop (XP Pro) which stopped booting a couple of weeks ago.  The symptoms are that the laptop would display its DOS Toshiba splash screen, then the Windows (XP) boot screen would display, then a very brief blue screen flash, then back to the boot options screen (offering safe mode, safe mode with networking etc, last known good config, etc... none of these work).

I assumed a duff HD, and swapped it for a new one and reinstalled from a TrueImage backup.  This worked until I installed windows updates I think (the backup was a few months old), and now the PC is doing the same thing.

I have installed a third, old HD (60GB) with Ubuntu 11.04 on it, and everything is fine.  PC boots and runs Ubuntu beautifully.  I need Windows running on it though !

Given these symptoms, could it a windows update issue ?  Or might I have a hardware fault still ?